# Display database values that are changed dynamically and change the value of the progressbar

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database, dynamic

I am new to c# and wpf. I have created a SQL Server database table and it gets displayed on my table in wpf. My problem is that I want the initial display table to be empty and as the values are added on the database table, it should reflect on display table. This dynamic process should then be linked to my progress bar that changes by 10% every time a new value is displayed.

So it would need an auto refresh of the Textblocks (say every 10 seconds) to check if a new value has been updated in the database and then display that value and change the progress.

How do I go about this?

This is my code for progress bar.

```
private void loadprogressbar()
{
        Duration dur = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        DoubleAnimation dblani = new DoubleAnimation(200.0, dur);
        pb1.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, dblani);
}
```

And this is my code for the display table.

```
private void WeightVital()
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-QTFGN00; Initial Catalog=VITALS;Integrated Security=true");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Weight FROM Vitals WHERE(VitalsID = 1)", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dataset);

        if(dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
        {
            string weight = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Weight"].ToString();
            textBlock18.Text = weight;
        }
}

private void HeightVital()
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-QTFGN00; Initial Catalog=VITALS;Integrated Security=true");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Height FROM Vitals WHERE(VitalsID = 1)", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dataset);

        if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string height = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Height"].ToString();
            textBlock19.Text = height;
        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0) Create an Object to represent your "Vital" row

1) Bind an `ObservableCollection<Vital>`to your DataGrid's `ItemSource`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding vitalList}" />
```

2) Fill this `ObservableCollection<T>` with your data

```
vitalList.Add(myNewVital);
```

3) Since ObservableCollection fires an event when an item is added/removed or changed, add an handler to your ObservableCollection's `CollectionChanged` event and either add your pourcentage or calculate it based on the Collection's `Count` property

```
vitalList.CollectionChange += myProgressBarHandler;
```

Comment: I created an ObservableCollection<Vitalview> and set all the incoming values into a datatable which works fine. My query is displayed in the datagrid but my UI doesnt update automatically if my database value is updated (I need to exit the screen and run my application again for the new values to be displayed.) Please help. I can post my code here, if you'd like. Thank you

Comment: Well your application has no clue about what is the current state of your database. an ObservableCollection will trigger an `CollectionChange` event when you `Add` (or edit/remove) an element. So your application needs to run the query again (based on time, event, anything else, ...), and add to the collection items that weren't previously there. You could also reassign the whole collection if you need to. Make sure you raise INotifyPropertyChanged also